# How to separate a comma delimited file and place each word in a variable?

Tags: bash, loops, unix

I have a `file.txt` that contains these lines:

```
P1,1,3,5
P2,2,4,6
P3,3,6,7
P4,4,7,8
```

I need to set each word in a variable to be use for an operation later.
Ex.

```
name1=P1; v1=1; x1=3; y1=5
```

then

```
name2=P2; v2=2; x2=4; y2=6
```

My code:

```
while IFS=, read -r name1 v1 x1 y1
do
    echo "$name1 $v1 $x1 $y1"
done < filecomma.txt
```

How can you place each entry into a variable? Can a `for` loop do it?

Comment: You need an array.

Comment: doing this:
n=4<br>
for (( i=0; i<n; i++ ))<br>
do<br>
 IFS=","<br>
 read col1 col2 col3 col4<br>
 b[$i] = $col2<br>
done < tabfile<br>
<br>
Will this work????

Answer (score 2):

this will do what you want

```
for ((i = 1; ; i++)); do
    IFS=, read name$i v$i x$i y$i || break
done < file.txt
```